# How to configure Debezium to use specific column as Kafka message key?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

By default, Debezium uses the primary key of the table as a message key. For example, if you have a table

```sql
create table users
(
    id            bigint auto_increment primary key,
    department_id bigint
);
```

with data

```
+----+----------------+
| id | department_id  |
+----+----------------+
|  5 |              1 |
|  6 |              1 |
|  7 |              2 |
+----+----------------+
```

Debezium will produce the following Kafka messages:

```
Key: {"id": 5} Value: {"id": 5, "department_id": 1}
Key: {"id": 6} Value: {"id": 6, "department_id": 1}
Key: {"id": 7} Value: {"id": 7, "department_id": 2}
```

The question is how to configure Debezium to use `department_id` or any other column as Kafka message key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `message.key.columns` parameter for this. In your connector's configuration, you should set it like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "mysql",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.whitelist": "my_database",
    ...
    "message.key.columns": "my_database.users:department_id"
  }
}
```

This parameter is supported by all the relational Debezium connectors.

You can find more information here:

https://debezium.io/blog/2019/09/26/debezium-0-10-0-cr2-released/
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/assemblies/cdc-mysql-connector/as_deploy-the-mysql-connector.html#mysql-connector-configuration-properties_debezium

Comment: Just keep in mind that your topic shouldn't be compacted then, as you wouldn't keep the last event per user but the last event per department after compaction. Also, when changing the department of a user, these events might end up in different partitions, so you wouldn't have any guaranteed ordering.